# Two Admin Backends as One

Tags: php, widget

Assume there are two separate web applications:

1. a sports site with admin backend
2. an email marketing application also with an admin backend

I want to be able to administer the marketing application from the sport's backend so that I don't have to open two separate admin interfaces.

My questions are as follows:

**1)**

How is this achieved? How can I embed the email admin backend into the sport's backend so that I operate the two from one place? Let's say both applications are in PHP.

Lets assume both applications are from the same Framework (Yii or Zend or CakePHP etc..).

**2) EXTRA QUESTION::**

Assuming the applications are in **different PHP Frameworks** , how can it be done?

I hope my question is clear. I have tried googling the issue but couldn't find any answers. If there is a tutorial somewhere, kindly point me there.

Comment: First, you need to look at the cost of making those two things go to one interface if they weren't written for it, compared to the cost of just using 2 interfaces.  I think you're going to find the time, money and effort required to accomplish what you want would be more difficult than you think (unless they're both written from the same platform... Joomla, whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant see any problems here at all? Most frameworks allow you to connect to multiple databases, so just create a general admin that has pages for both websites, connecting to the correct database for each page. You would be able to choose whatever framework you want. The general backend for both sites can be on any domain. The only drawback i can think of is if one database is on another server it will be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some kind of bridging software between the two applications (you don't say what they are), or some ***very*** common ground, you'll likely have to write such an interface yourself.  Both sites depend on different code and data to accomplish similar tasks, and you'll have to "introduce them to eah other" so that they can work together.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What do you mean i don't say what they are?

Comment: What the frameworks or source you're using - are they both "joomla", or both "Yii".  You just said "a sports site" and "a marketing application".  Not that it necessarily matters, but unless they're very, very, very similar, the likelihood of shared admin functions is virtually zero.

Comment: Ok thanks. Lets assume both are from the same Framework. I have updated the post.

Comment: Another comment is substantiating what I've answered with - no offense, but if you don't understand the complications of the technical aspect of the admin functions, the cost of building such an undertaking is very likely far beyond what you're envisioning.